# How to change background color for every other row in a ListView?

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to change the the background color for every second row in a ListView?

I figured it should be doable with an if statement that recognises if it is a even or odd row and choose the style based on this. However, it does not seem possible to utilise this in React-Native.

My renderRow function looks like this:

```
renderRow={(rowData) => {
          return (
        <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() => this.props.onSelectNote(rowData)}
          style={styles.rowStyle}
          underlayColor="#9E7CE3"
        >
          <Text style={styles.rowText}>{rowData.title}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>              )
        }
      }
```

As of now all rows will be styled according to rowStyle. How would it be possible to have different styles for different rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an ID to `rowData` to know if the row you're rendering is even or odd, and then use a custom style for all even/odd rows.

Something like:

```
renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) => {
    let evenRow = rowData.id % 2 == 0;
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => this.props.onSelectNote(rowData)}
        style={[styles.rowStyle, evenRow && styles.evenRowStyle}
        underlayColor="#9E7CE3"
      >
        <Text style={styles.rowText}>{rowData.title}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It doesn't work however. I logged the rowID's to console and apparently these are numbers such as 1454594588447 and 1454594592183. None are even! How are these generated?

Comment: Ok I have to admit that I didn't test this so mea culpa... is there a way that you could pass an index inside `rowData` to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I made a counter that works like an index and now your solution works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Weird. Whenever I use rowID, I get normal incrementing IDs (1, 2, 3..).